# Sending Selected Items to a Cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get the items that I have and initiate all the separate items into its own respective cell.

```
With Me.selecteditems
    For i = 1 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(i) Then
            found = True
            On Error Resume Next
            str = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(9).Range("A1:Cells(i, 1)")
            quantity = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(9).Range("A1:Cells(i, 2)")
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

This part of the below code, is supposed to put the items that come from the longer part of the code and put in the item, `str`, and the amount, `quantity`. I tried different ways and just recently I tried repeating how it was before, it doesn't come out that well. Also without the error it throws me:

> Application-defined or Object-defined Error

The Whole Code:

```
Dim i As Long, j As Long, ii As Long
Dim found As Boolean
Dim str As String
Dim message, title, defaultval As String
Dim quantity As String


With Me.selecteditems
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(i) Then
            found = True
            For ii = 0 To .ColumnCount - 1
                If str = "" Then
                    str = .List(i, ii) & vbTab
                Else
                    If ii < .ColumnCount - 1 Then
                        str = str & .List(i, ii) & vbTab
                    Else
                        str = str & .List(i, ii)
                    End If
                End If
            Next ii
            message = "How much" & vbCrLf & str & "?"
            title = "Amount"
            defaultval = "1"
            quantity = InputBox(message, title, defaultval)
            str = str & "  x  " & quantity & vbNewLine
        End If
    Next i
End With

With Me.selecteditems
    For i = 1 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(i) Then
            found = True
            On Error Resume Next
            str = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(9).Range("A1:Cells(i, 1)")
            quantity = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(9).Range("A1:Cells(i, 2)")
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: This syntax is wrong `str = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(9).Range("A1:Cells(i, 1)")`. What should it be doing?

Comment: I was hoping it would take the items from code above and put it in the cell because the item comes from a listbox

Comment: Should I just do `.Cells(i,1)`

Comment: Yes it looks as if this will do it `str = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(9).Cells(i, 1)` but this assigns the contents of a cell to a variable, it doesn't put anything into a cell.

Comment: Is there a way to put it in?

Comment: You just need to swap the two sides of that line so that `str` is on the right hand side.

Comment: It works, but it doesn't put it individually, but that might the be the bigger code

Comment: What do you mean by "put it individually"?

Comment: All the items are in one cell. Also the `quantity` write over eache other and leaves the last one